# Symfony3 return array from query to json

Tags: arrays, json, doctrine, symfony

I have problem, i can't return my posts array to json becouse symfony returns array with entity object?

Its my code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $posts = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findAll();

    return $this->json($posts);
}
```

I use $this->json is return json data, feature added on sf3.
But this is my result:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

i want to load my posts.

ps. i know, i can use Query builder, and method toArray or something, but is any method to use and DRY? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Because entity can have multiple boundaries, proxy objects and related entities, I personally prefer to explicitly specify what is about to be serialized, like this:

```
use JsonSerializable;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class SomeEntity implements JsonSerializable
{
    /** @Column(length=50) */
    private $title;

    /** @Column(length=50) */
    private $text;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'title' => $this->title,
            'text'  => $this->text,
        );
    }
}
```

And then it's as simple as `json_encode($someEntityInstance);`.

You can use [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) as well to accomplish your task DRY.

Also, there is an option to write your own serializer to normalize the data.

**UPDATE:**

If you want multiple representations of a JSON, it can be achieved like this:

```
use JsonSerializable;

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class SomeEntity implements JsonSerializable
{
    // ...

    protected $isList;

    public function toList()
    {
        $this->isList = TRUE;

        return $this;
    }

    private function jsonSerializeToList()
    {
        return [ // array representing list... ]
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        if( $this->isList ) {
            $normalized = $this->jsonSerializeToList();
        } else {
            $normalized = array(
                'title' => $this->title,
                'text'  => $this->text,
            );
        }

        return $normalized;
    }
}
```

And called as `json_encode($someEntityInstance->toList());`. Any way, this is a bit dirty, so I suggest to be consistent with an idea of the interface.

Comment: is option to create to 2 groups for jsonSerialize? For example i have post:
one jsonSerialize for list: id, title and one jsonSerialize for post details:
id, title, content, tags etc.

Comment: Well, it should be kind of consistent, same as entity returned by Doctrine, unless you write and define custom query. However, there is a way to hack through it. See update.

Answer (score 2):

A best solution is to enable the serializer component in Symfony:

```
#app/config/config.yml
framework:
   serializer:      ~
```

Note: the serializer component is disabled by default, you have to uncomment the config line in app/config/config.yml file.

Comment: This give me error: A circular reference has been detected (configured limit: 1).

Comment: Maybe you have a circular reference exception because the Post entity has a relationship with another entity which in turn refers to the entity Post. Check out this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-circular-references

Comment: Yes, i have relation post to category, i dont know how to do this :/

Comment: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-serialization-groups    https://gist.github.com/frieser/ac5e395c271e050d4d6e399b7353d858   https://gist.github.com/frieser/75177d1a0c1dd5d0c639612394a5d8b6